# How to show a toast above the status bar in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, toast, android-toast

I am trying to show a toast message (not a string but a view using the `toast.setView`) above the status bar but no luck till now.
I have tried `toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)` it shows the toast at the top but doesn't go above the status bar. I have read some old answers and they mentioned about adding custom flags to the `WindowManager.LayoutManager` of android core `Toast.java` but i don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me with this? or is there a better way to show a view at the top? I am showing this on certain conditions when my app is in the background & another thing is I don't want to ask for Draw over other apps permission in the runtime. I know this is possible as some of the app in the playstore is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use lower API, or another type of view

```
 /**
         * Set the location at which the notification should appear on the screen.
         *
         * <p><strong>Warning:</strong> Starting from Android {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#R}, for apps
         * targeting API level {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#R} or higher, this method is a no-op when
         * called on text toasts.
         *
         * @see android.view.Gravity
         * @see #getGravity
         */
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: since API R gravity don't support text toasts, but  you can use a snack bar instead
https://material.io/develop/android/components/snackbars

Comment: in my project I use: https://github.com/matecode/Snacky